Canonical evaluation map and Chern classes
Suppose we have a globally generated line bundle $L$ on a smooth projective surface $X$. Then, we have the following short exact sequence,
$$0\to M_L\to H^0(X,L)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X\to L\to 0$$
I am tying to calculate the Chern classes of $M_L$. I am not sure, but I believe $H^0(X,L)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus h^0(X,L)}?$ If this is indeed true, then we have $$\operatorname{ch}_0(H^0(X,L)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X)=h^0(X,L),\  \operatorname{ch}_1(H^0(X,L)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X)=0=\operatorname{ch}_2(H^0(X,L)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X).$$ Hence,
$$\operatorname{ch}_0(M_L)=h^0(X,L)-1,\ \operatorname{ch}_1(M_L)=-\operatorname{ch}_0(M_L)L,\ \operatorname{ch}_2(M_L)=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{ch}_0(M_L)L^2.$$
Is this correct?

$\mathrm{ch}_0$ is correct, $\mathrm{ch}_1$ and $\mathrm{ch}_2$ are not.

For $H^0(X,L)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X$?

No, for the kernel M_L

But, isn't $0=\operatorname{ch}_1(H^0(X,L)\otimes \mathcal{O}_X)=\operatorname{ch}_1(L)\cdot \operatorname{ch}_0(M_L)+\operatorname{ch}_1(M_L)\cdot \operatorname{ch}_0(L)=\operatorname{ch}_0(M_L)L+\operatorname{ch}_1(M_L)$?

Chern character is additive (not multiplicative) in exact sequences.

So, it should be $\operatorname{ch}_1(M_L)=-L,\operatorname{ch}_2(M_L)=-\frac{L^2}{2}?$
